# If statement does not work if maximum is reached

Tags: php

I'm working on a setup code to setup your account i have a IF statement if total_not <= 40 it has to do nothing because you've reached the maximum notifications. But this does not work how do i fix this?

Code:

```
<?php

        // Set the database access information (add your own database credentials below)
        xxxxx

        // Connect to the database
        $dbc = @mysqli_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

        // Check for shout removal


        // Check for shout submission
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // Empty error array
            $error = array();

            // Check for a shout
            if(empty($_POST['email']))
            {
                $error[] = "Oeps! Er is iets fout gegaan!";
            }

            // If there are no errors, insert shout into the database.
            // Otherwise, display errors.
            if(sizeof($error) == 0)
            {
                // Clean data
                $mijn_les = $_POST['mijn_les'];
                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);


                // Insert shout
                $query = "UPDATE users SET user_email = '$email', user_tid = '$mijn_les' WHERE user_name = '{$_SESSION['user_name']}'";
                $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

                // Display confirmation

            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>

            <strong>Gelukt!</strong> Je account is ingesteld! <a href='../signin.php?logout' class='alert-link'>Klik hier</a> om opnieuw in te loggen!
          </div>";

            $hide = "style='display: none;'";

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    if($num_rows <= 40)
    {
        $send_not = "INSERT INTO notif (send_to, grav_url, send_by, notif_text) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['user_name']}', 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a72776fb2702ba915e2327618414bb15', 'Admin', 'Leraar Setup compleet! U kunt nu onze website gebruiken!')";
                $not_add = @mysqli_query($dbc, $send_not) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));    
    }
            } else {

                // Display error message
                foreach($error as $value)
                {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>

            <strong>Oeps!</strong> Er is iets mis gegaan! Probeer het opnieuw!
          </div>";   
                }

            }
        }



    ?>
```

Comment: `num_rows` : gets the number of rows in a result set, which means the update result that will never be `>=40` and this insert query will be executed everytime `INSERT INTO notif`.  to fix this you should add a `select count(id_notif) from notif where ...` and then you could use the value of `num_rows`

Comment: `num_rows` gets the number of rows from a `select`, you are `update`ing.  Try `affected_rows`.  But it looks like it will be only `1`.

Comment: @Simo make it an answer thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
 if($num_rows <= 40) {...}
```

By

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) <= 40) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

`num_rows` : gets the number of rows in a result set, which means the update result will never be `>= 40` and the `insert` query will be executed everytime.

So you should use `SELECT COUNT(id_notif) as total_notif FROM notif where user_email = '$email'` and `total_notif` instead of `$num_rows`